# Regular Expression Longest Possible Matching

Tags: regex

I have an input string which is a directory address:

Example: `ProgramFiles/Micro/Telephone`

And I want to match it against a list of words very strictly:

Example: `Tel|Tele|Telephone`

I want to match against `Telephone` and not `Tel`. Right now my regex looks like this:

```
my( $output ) = ( $input =~ m/($list)/o );
```

The regex above will match against `Tel`. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Place your preferred match first?

Comment: What language are you working in?

Comment: Placing your preferred match first isn't always possible - for example, I'm currently generating a list of possible keywords to match on the concept of "Flat Number"; my data is multi-language and messy. I might see "Flt" or "Apartment" or "Apt", or "Apartment Number", or "Apartamento No"... The list goes on! Trying to build and maintain a regular expression which is going to match on all of these concepts, where everything is in exactly the right order is nearly practically impossible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want a whole word match:

```
\b(Tel|Tele|Telephone)\b
```

`\b` is a zero-width word boundary. Word boundary in this case means the transition from or to a word character. A word character (`\w`) is `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`.

If you simply want to match against the longest in a partial word match put the longest first. For example:

```
\b(Telephone|Tele|Tel)
```

or

```
(Telephone|Tele|Tel)
```

Comment: My list cannot be guaranteed to have the longest word first.

Comment: The word boundary works thought. But I cannot follow the reasoning as to why it worked.

Comment: @syker if you want partial matches, the easiest way to construct the expression is to sort the list of words, reverse the order and then join all the words with `|` in between and that'll give the correct ordering of large words with smaller word matches.

Comment: Yea, I was thinking of the sort-and-reverse-order approach. I like the zero-width boundary approach a lot though. Are there any drawbacks to the zero-width boundary approach?

Comment: Using the word boundaries (\b) would mean that, for example, `\b(Tel|Tele)\b` would not match anything in your original string.

Answer (score 2):

Change the orders: `Tel|Tele|Telephone` to `Telephone|Tele|Tel`.
By the regexp algorithm, alternation is searched from left-to-right, if there found a match, that's it, no greedy matching.
For example: /a|ab|abc/ working on "abc" matches "a" instead of the most greedy "abc".

or use the matching expressions.

```
Tel(?:e(?:phone)?)?
```

Comment: how safe is it to rely on this behaviour? Is it in the regex spec or something somewhere? It would be really nice for me to be able to rely on the `(XXX|XX|X)` form for what I'm implementing

Answer (score -1):

How about trying to find a match, as long as the longest match is not anywhere in the input?
Something like:

Find telephone, OR find tel, and tele where telephone is not anywhere in the input. So, to start making it look like a regex:

(telephone) OR
characters without telephone, followed by (tel|tele) followed by characters without telephone

(telephone|.*(telephone){0}.*(tel|tele).*(telephone){0}.*)

Does that make any sense?